# Is it possible a schema type that gets the value of one property of already defined schema type

Tags: graphql, schema

I have a schema that looks like this.

```
exports.typeDefs = gql`
type User {
   userid: ID!
   name: String
}

type Post {
   post_id: ID!
   post_category: String!
   post_type: String!
   post_hashtag: String
   user: User
 }
 `;
```

Now post have the field named "post_hashtag".
I want to define another schema type and get that post_hashtag property for all the nodes in post type.
of post.
I tried the below type hashtag and put a cipher query on that.

```
type hashtag{
        post_hashtag: String
               @cypher[statement: "MATCH (n:Test_Temp) RETURN n.post_hashtag"]
     }
```

But it returns only the one first found hashtag and save it on hashtag node. This is not what I want. I want all the hashtags that are available in any post_hashtag node.

Example: If I query

```
query{
    hashtag{
       post_hashtag
    }
}
```

This should give all the hashtags that are available in any of the post node but instead it return only one hashtag.

I've been trying this since few days. going through different solutions but none worked.
Any suggestions Please.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. Actually, we just need to use the `collect` method of neo4j to return an array of hashtags and save it in the hashtag node. And it will save all the hashtags on the node and we can retrieve them later.

First, change the schema a little bit like this.

```
type hashtag{
        post_hashtag: [String]
               @cypher[statement: "MATCH (n:Test_Temp) RETURN 
 n.post_hashtag"]
     }
```

Notice: I've changed the post_hashtag type and made it an array of strings.

Then just the cipher query will change by the one down below.

```
MATCH (n:Test_Temp) RETURN collect(n.post_hashtag)
```

And it is done.